# How to set hazelcast tcp strategy?

Tags: hazelcast

We are running services on a cluster as docker containers.

Since we cannot use eureka or multicast, we are trying to use hazelcast TCP discovery.Currently, configuration is like this (example):

```
  cluster:
    enabled: true
    hazelcast:
      useSiteLocalInterfaces: true
      discovery:
        tcp:
          enabled: true
          members:
          - 10.10.10.1
          - 10.10.10.2
          - 10.10.10.3
        azure:
          enabled: false
        multicast:
          enabled: false
        kubernetesDns:
          enabled: false
```

During service start, we get the following log message:
`Members configured for TCP Hazelcast Discovery after removing local addresses: [10.10.10.1, 10.10.10.2, 10.10.10.3]`

That means, the service didn't discover its local ip right.

Later in the log, the following message appears: `[LOCAL] [hazelcast-test-service:hz-profile] [3.12.2] Picked [172.10.0.1]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=5701], bind any local is true`

Obviously, the services determines its local ip to be 172.10.0.1. We have no idea, where this ip comes from. It doesn't exist on the cluster.

Is there a way to give hazelcast a hint how to discover its local ip?

Comment: 172,10,0,1 is a Docker IP.

Answer (score 0):

The address `172.10.0.1` must be one of the network interfaces inside your container. You can ssh into your Docker container and check the network interfaces (e.g. with `ifconfig`).

If you want to use another network interface, you can configure it with the environment variable `HZ_NETWORK_PUBLICADDRESS`. For example, in your case, one of the members can be started with the following docker command.

```
docker run -e HZ_NETWORK_PUBLICADDRESS=10.10.10.1:5701 -p 5701:5701 hazelcast/hazelcast
```

Please read more at [Hazelcast Docker Image: Hazelcast Hello World](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-docker#hazelcast-hello-world)